# Edit text file with batch file under Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've got an issue regarding a text file I'd like to change with a batch file. I was able to trim it to this point.

```
3539    
78060031              
523        )
```

What I need now is to get the numbers in the same line. By the way the text file is not written by my programm. What I need is now to get some backspaces till it looks like this:

```
353978060031523
```

I know there is a simple solution, but since I'm very bad in scripting I can't
find it.
Sorry for my bad english and the bad post! 
It's the first time I post something here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much now it looks like that:
3539  78060031  523        )
i would like to erase the spaces and the ) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicated question. But, well, nevermind, I just answer your question.
I don't know what's the purpose of a ")" behind the "523", but since you're just concatenate the string, try out the following script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (hxh-chp.txt) do (
    set "concatenate_string=!concatenate_string!%%a"
)

echo !concatenate_string!
pause >nul
```

Comment: Thank you very much now it looks like that:
3539  78060031  523        )
i would like to erase the spaces and the ) thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you expect, that is, concatenate the numerical characters and removing all spaces and the `)`:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "usebackq" %%L in ("\path\to\your\text_file.txt") do (
    set "CONCAT=!CONCAT!%%L"
)
endlocal & set "CONCAT=%CONCAT%"
echo %CONCAT%
```

This code makes use of the default behaviour of `for /F`, where the option `tokens=1` and `delims` is tab and space.